# Dynamic textbox generation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a textbox in which user enters a number between 1 to 10. Based on the number entered in the textbox those many textboxes have to be generated dynamically (i mean without pressing any button). Can anyone help me out in doing this??

Answer (score 4):

```
<input id="input" />
<div id="space"></div>
<script>
$("#input").keyup(function(){
    var $count = $(this).val();
    $("#space").html('');
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {

     $("#space").append('<input name="'+$count+'_input" />');
    }

});
</script>
```

demo: http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d6046.php

Comment: oooh, dammit :D I'm  enthusiast jQuerian :p I missed it. Execuse me

Answer (score 0):

[element.onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange)

```
document.getElementById("YourId").onchange = function(){
   alert("The text in the textbox has changed");
}
```

Comment: That requires the user to leave the textbox, which counts, I think, as pressing a button.